# pip3 not working on ubuntu 20.04: "has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'"

Tags: 20.04, python3, pip

On Ubuntu 20.04 i have installed pip3 with the following command:
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

But when I run `pip3` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

In a virtual-environment the `pip3` command works fine however.

As suggested in other answers I have tried reinstalling python3 and pip3, all without success. A lot of other answers use pip3 to solve the problem, but I'm unable to run pip3.

I have noticed that several other programs (docker-compose, Guake) give me a similar error.

I run python 3.8.2. And when I open an virtual-environment I can see that my pip3 version is 20.0.2.

Comment: This is not an issue with pip, I'd be curious to what "other questions" you are referring to, is the error the same? Your setuptools is either out-of-date, or your Python installation is broken. Is APT happy with the current state of your system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently experienced this with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well. After lengthy troubleshooting, I was able to resolve this by running:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: This did not work for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error as well, the only thing that worked was the following after troubleshooting and seeing python3 installed at 3.8.2 but pip or pip3 command not found:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

After this, everything worked fine. It looks like it installs python dev related packages including pip that was missing.

Note: This was for Ubuntu 20.04 specifically to get python and pip commands working properly.